# How do I change the colour of an object in Python-Tkinter-Canvas after a delay

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I'm the absolute beginner here...
I've made a small program where I use a buttonclick to change the colour of an object (Canvas oval).
I make it yellow at start and change it by the command from the button.
Now I want it to switch back to yellow after a dwell time. All I have tried results in a pause and it is yellow all the time. I try to establish a function with two buttons, one "ok" and one "false", each button should change the colour shortly to green and red, respectively. After a short while it should turn to yellow again, waiting for the next click.
Anyone that can help me further?

## My code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")
root.title("LedLight")

# Class
class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    # Button
    self.push()
    # Led
    self.signal("yellow")

# Button
    def push(self):
        self.btn1 = Button(self, text="PUSH", command=self.pushed,
                           bg='green', fg='white', width=8, height=2,
                           relief="raised", borderwidth=8,
                           font=("Arial Black", 12))
        self.btn1.place(x=250, y=300)

# Led
    def signal(self, colour):
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, height=100, width=100)
        self.led1 = self.canvas.create_oval(50, 50, 100, 100, fill=colour)
        self.canvas.place(x=230, y=100)

# Function
    def pushed(self):
        self.signal("green")

app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do some research on the `after` method that tkinter provides.

Comment: I did try that, but I just can't figure out where to put it. Either nothing happens or the application makes a paus when I push the button.
I like to think that it should be icncluded in the function "pushed", but it just stops the execution and the led never turns green. 

    def pushed(self):
        self.signal("green")
        self.after(200, self.signal("yellow"))